# How to sign a Azure Storage Request on dotnet core / netstandard2.0

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-storage

On full framework with nuget windowsazure.storage I had access to 
SharedKeyAuthenticationHandler, which could sign a HttpWebRequest for me. I am porting my library to dotnet standard 2.0 and is missing this implementation now to do the signing.

Since storage sdk supports netstandard 1.0, and 1.3 - the method to actually do the signing on those specifications must be there somewhere but I cannot find it.

This is the method I am trying to port

```
    public virtual async Task SignRequestAsync(HttpWebRequest request, TenantRoute route)
    {
        var account = await GetStorageAccountAsync(route);             

        var a = new SharedKeyAuthenticationHandler(SharedKeyCanonicalizer.Instance, account.Credentials, account.Credentials.AccountName);
        a.SignRequest(request, null);

    }
```

Comment: ``I am porting my library to dotnet standard 2.0 and is missing this implementation now to do the signing`` It seems that [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.Protocol
      Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.auth.protocol?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azurestorage-8.1.3) is removed.

Comment: but its only removed at coding time. When i run, i can get the classes in the debugger. so not really sure why